# Maximum value such that hyperbolic paraboloid fits in cylindrical shaped box with given radius.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm struggling with this this exercise for quite a bit. It goes as follows:

Pringles chips are shaped like a hyperbolic paraboloid, with equation:$$z(xy)=\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}$$
with the limitation $x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}\leq q^2$

Determine the maximum value of q such that the chip fit in the cylindrical shaped box with a radius of 2.

**My thoughtprocess**

so when $q=1$ we get: $$x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}\leq 1$$
[image]

But now I don't now by how much I have to change q in order to get the right fit.
I know that $$x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}\leq 1$$ would fit the circle with radius 2, but that is not wat is being asked.

somehow I need to implement:
$$z(xy)=\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}$$

But I don't know how :(

If someone knows how to get the answer and would be willing to share it, your awesome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any limitations for the height of the box?

Comment: More likely than not, your question is not framed correctly or is missing info. Otherwise you have already mentioned that $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$ fits in the circle of radius $2$. That is  $q^2 = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the height $z$ is irrelevant, assuming the chips are aligned with the container in such a way that the axes specifying their shapes coincide.

In such a case, the requirement $x^2 + y^2 \le 2^2$ and $x^2 + y^2/2 \le q^2$ suggests letting $x = 2 \cos \theta$, $y = 2 \sin \theta$, hence $$q^2 \ge 4 \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta = 2 + 2 \cos^2 \theta.$$The smallest value of $\cos^2 \theta$ being $0$, it follows that $q^2 \ge 2$, hence $q = \sqrt{2}$ maximizes the size of the chip.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but it seems like the problem is 3d and you could rotate the chips to maximize $q$. I mean that you could put it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlZaf.png

Comment: @NikolayEbel I clearly stated my assumptions at the beginning of my answer.  Without this assumption, the question as posed lacks sufficient information to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @heropup, for sharing your answer!

Comment: @heropup, could you please explain why you need more information? It seems to me that what you need to find here is a "minimal projection," i.e. such a projection that its diameter $d$ (maximal distance between two points) is minimal among others. The condition to fit then is the condition that $d<4$. Though it seems to be not so easy technically, I don't see which additional information you need.

Comment: @NikolayEbel Note that $z$ is also a function of some parameter $a$.  If you plot the shape of the chip for varying values of $a$, you will find that if you allow for rotation in the container, then there is a highly nontrivial dependence of the maximal $q$ on an additional *translation* in the container that would make the chip fit.  If you admit rotations when the problem does not explicitly state it, then I see no reason why one should exclude translations.  The resulting problem becomes extremely complex and probably not what was intended.

Comment: @heropup I agree that it seems to be non trivial, but I didn’t get how translations modify the idea that you need to consider projections and find “the smallest” one (check the picture I attached in the first comment). Size of the projection doesn’t depend on shifts. And I don’t see a connection between complexity and the lack of information.